# Filling a trapezoid with a bitmap brush

Tags: wpf, 3d

I am looking to fill a [trapezoid](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trapezoid) with a bitmap brush so that it appears 3D-like. So basically map each of the vertices to corners of the bitmap and paint everything accordingly.

I know there is nothing readily available in WPF but I was looking for a quick and dirty solution that gives at least a good simulation of this effect. Any ideas are welcome except I'd like to refrain from using WPF-3D (unless the proposed solution is utterly simple).

Comment: Seems like you're looking for [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/greg_schechter/archive/2007/10/26/enter-the-planerator-dead-simple-3d-in-wpf-with-a-stupid-name.aspx). BTW, no WPF is not bitmap-based, and you should not use bitmaps at all if possible.

Comment: After fiddling with this for a couple of days, I can absolutely confirm that this works for me. It does use WPF-3D which I tried to avoid but it is really doing a nice job. If you'd like to enter an answer instead, I'd gladly accept it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for the [Planerator](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/greg_schechter/archive/2007/10/26/enter-the-planerator-dead-simple-3d-in-wpf-with-a-stupid-name.aspx).

It is a control that uses WPF's 3D capabilities to create a "plane projection" of it's contents:

[image]

Usage:

```
<pl:Planerator RotationY="35">
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" ... >
        <StackPanel>
            <Label  FontSize="24" Content=" " Foreground="#FF000000"/>

            <Border ... >
                <MediaElement x:Name="myMediaElement" />
            </Border>
        </StackPanel>

        <ListBox ... />

    </StackPanel>
</pl:Planerator>
```

Full source code included in the link above.